# How to declare a nodejs global variable to avoid race condition between proceses

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, cucumber, javascript-objects, wdio-v6

Question: How can I declare a Nodejs global variable that gets updated multiple times in a session for a process? I am using this global variable in multiple processes. And wants to keep the data of this global variable separated between the processes.

I have currently declared a global variable like `global.object1={};` in my cucumber hooks file. And I update its value a few times in my tests. As far as it is 1 test, it works just fine. But when multiple tests run, I am getting race condition. Data from **test1** appears in **test2**. And hence **test2** fails. It is visible in logs that test2 is showing data from test1.

In my test, I am trying to keep the data unique between the tests. I have read about a few related blogs and Stackoveflow queries but it's not clear to me what exactly I can do.

My previous approach was to store objects data in a JSON file in separate locations. But this is not how I want to code. I have used Java before and have synchronised my objects to use them between threads. But I am not sure how I can do it here using Nodejs and ES6.

Any leads are welcome.